# A Test failure after upgrading Selenium 3 to 4

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc

I have upgraded the application from selenium 3 to selenium 4 and found that some of the test cases getting failed after upgradation with below error message.

```
com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: Timed out waiting for action to finish
at com.thoughtworks.selenium.webdriven.Timer.run(Timer.java:46)
at com.thoughtworks.selenium.webdriven.WebDriverCommandProcessor.execute(WebDriverCommandProcessor.java:181)
at com.thoughtworks.selenium.webdriven.WebDriverCommandProcessor.doCommand(WebDriverCommandProcessor.java:95)
at com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium.waitForPageToLoad(DefaultSelenium.java:816)
```

The test cases are getting failed on below line.

```
SeleniumSession.get().waitForPageToLoad();
```

**SeleniumSession is internal class which is extending DefaultSeleniumSession class**

The default timeout configured for these test cases is 3 min.

Can you please help to understand how we can fix this issue. Or do we have any alternate method in selenium 4 to achieve the waitForPageToLoad.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this error you may use the `WebDriverWait` like below

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 120);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//your/xpath/here")));
```

***OR***

You can use the `PageLoadStrategy` that introduce in selenium 4. Like below

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setPageLoadStrategy(PageLoadStrategy.NORMAL);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

You can also combine the above both and use it like this

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.urlContains("example.com"));
```

You can read more about the `PageLoadStrategy` from [here](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/drivers/options/)

***import***

```
import org.openqa.selenium.PageLoadStrategy;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
```

Comment: Actually, This issue is occurring while clicking on ok button in popup window.
After click on OK button, below method got used to wait for pageload.
SeleniumSession.get().waitForPageToLoad(); 

After completion of above statement, it should route to main page of the application. 
We are not passing any xpath or id or name parameter to it.

So I am not sure what details I need to provide while using above solution.

Comment: You have to do some action after the page load right ? So use the explicit wait after that `click` to wait for element to perform desire action like I have mentioned in my answer above.